# AJAX cross-domain "convert" to Postmessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postmessage

I have ajax cross-domain request.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(xml) {
            $('.post-msg').append(processXml(xml, config));
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorMsg = "Request on url: " + url + " failed: " + textStatus + " error:" + errorThrown;
            alert(errorMsg);
        }
    });
```

And i need "convert" this using technology Postmessage(https://github.com/daepark/postmessage). Earlier I did not worked with such things.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's important to ask just the one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

> But it doesn't work on IE < 10. And i need "convert" this using technology POST message. Earlier I did not worked with such things.

These are two completely separate and unrelated things.

The reason it doesn't work in IE < 10 is that IE < 10 [doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) CORS with the standard `XMLHttpRequest` object that jQuery uses to provide the `ajax` function. IE8 and IE9 *do* support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), but only with the Microsoft-specific `XDomainRequest` object rather than `XMLHttpRequest`. jQuery does not provide this cross-browser behavior (see [this issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283) in the jQuery issue tracker). There is at least one plug-in available that does, according to that ticket.

As for changing it from a `GET` to a `POST`, that's literally just changing

```
type: "GET",
```

to

```
type: "POST",
```

But again, it has nothing to do with the IE problem.

Comment: I wrote about the IE, because it was the initial reason of all problems. My issue - is to write a similar request using the post Message

Comment: @GeraySuinov: The second part of the answer should solve it, then. It literally is that small a change.